# Bootstrap accordion don't close all of the list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange problem with my accordion list in bootstrap. There's always one list item opened and all of them doesn't close. If one is open and I click another list to open, then only the first one would close.

But I want that it also closes on toggle.

Any idea what I am missing?

### Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container width-fix">
        <div class="col-md-7 faq left-side">
         <h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
            <h6>Click on questions to expand answers</h6>

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title active-panel" id="panel-title1">
          <span class="arrow"></span>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.:
        </a>

      </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title2" data-title="2" >
           <span class="arrow"></span>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?
        </a>

      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
          ANSWER ME! 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title3" data-title="3">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, coortis id nisi nec dapibus.?
        </a>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        ANSWER ME TOO!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title4">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
         Lorem ipit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.? 
        </a>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        ANSWERS!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title5">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
         Lor adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.?
        </a>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        I WANT ANSWERS!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title2" data-title="2" >
           <span class="arrow"></span>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.?
        </a>

      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
          ANSWER ME! 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title3" data-title="3">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .?
        </a>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        ANSWER ME TOO!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEight">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title4">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEight">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .? 
        </a>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        ANSWERS!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNine">
      <h4 class="panel-title" id="panel-title5">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNine">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed loborti?
            <span class="arrow"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseNine" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        I WANT ANSWERS!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>                   



</div>
         <br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5 faq right-side">
            <h2><img src="<?php print variable_get('theme_url', ''); ?>/images/feedback.png">&nbsp;Feedback</h2>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis id nisi nec dapibus.:</p>





        </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the panel body to show by default:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

If you want the panel body to hide by default:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Aditya. But it gives me this error 
`TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion'`, even when I provide the parent Div ID to it. Any Idea?

Comment: I think @Steve means the Bootstrap accordion, not jQueryUI

Comment: Thanks Aditya, it now doesn't open by default, and we have to click to open it, but I am unable to close it when I click back on it. It only closes when another list opens.

Comment: So this is the JFiddle of it. It works fine here but something in my Drupal is conflicting with it. I know this goes out of scope but what do you think could be conflicting with it when I click to close it? As it just doesn't close on toggl. http://jsfiddle.net/fzN4K/30/

Comment: What error are you getting on your browser console ?

Comment: Nothing. but something else works. When I changed my old bootstrap JS with newer one at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js, it worked! So we're good :). Accepting and + 1. Thanks :)